# Initializing Virtual Functions in .cpp files

Tags: c++

I have looked up how to initialize functions from the .h file and know that you call `virtual` when declaring the function which I did.

`.h file`

```
class Stuff{
public:
    virtual void dostuff(double x);
};
```

But when I try and initialize the function in the .cpp file I keep getting red-line errors.

`.cpp file`

```
Stuff:: dostuff(double x) = 0;
```

This gives me a "Stuff::dostuff" may not be redeclared outside its class.

```
void dostuff(double x) = 0;
```

Gives me function "dostuff" may not be initialized. I am including the dostuff.h file in the .cpp file. My question is how do I correctly initialize a virtual function in the .cpp file?

Comment: You're aren't initialising anything here. You're *declaring,* in the .h file, and *defining,* in the .cpp file. You can't put the `= 0` part in the definition.

Comment: You probably meant `virtual void dostuff(double x) = 0;` if you wanted a pure virtual function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I try and initialize the function in the .cpp file I keep getting red-line errors.

You cannot initialize a function in C++. You can only declare and define them.

You have already declared the function inside the body of the class definition. If you want to define the function, you'll need to use:

```
void Stuff::dostuff(double x) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a pure virtual function you have to make its declaration to zero only at the time of declaration in class:

```
virtual void dostuff(double x) = 0;
```

You can't redeclare it.